# Fsanitize doesn't show any output on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, memory-leaks

I'm currently working on a C project on MacOS and it seems that using fsanitize doesn't works or doesn't output anything at the exit of my program, while with the same Makefile it works without problem on ArchLinux.

I've added the flag both on the compilation and linker:

```
CFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99
```

`LDFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -lssh -lreadline`

**my clang version :**
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/

It's weird as if my memory is good, it was working months ago.

Does someone have the same issue or know how I may solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html Does it stop your program? If not, no errors were detected. If you tried to intentionally create errors, that code might have been optimised away.

Comment: @gnasher729 No it doesn't stop my program, acting like flag wasn't here and exit with a 0 status code even then I have created leaks by allocating something on the memory.
I have also created a dummy program with just a malloc and no free, with no luck.
Also, I am running with -O1 and tried -O0